# HDMI input to USB output converter

Tags: hdmi, video, usb-c, video-adapters

I have a dock station with USB C. I want to connect it, only for the video, to my old PC that has a HDMI.

So, my PC is HDMI and it is the input for the USB C that is the output (and that is then connected to a monitor). Can I do it? Does this kind of hardware exists?

My PC also has a VGA port.

[image]

Comment: Information about the Dock is missing, inviting speculation.  So, voting to close.

Comment: Agreed, I think we need more information about the dock and clarity on how you want to use it. If the purpose is just to use it for video output, why not just use the video output on your laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but your monitor does not have HDMI and only USB-C?

If that's the case, there are no direct adapters as far as I know, only in the other direction. You can however, get HDMI to DisplayPort, which is the protocol the USB-C uses on your monitor. If you also have a DisplayPort, this is what you need, when you do not, try searching for a two way DP to  USB-C cable/adapter (those should exist, but I don't know where)

Edit, Do not use the dock, it will not work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go from HDMI to USB. You can however, go from USB-A to USB-C with [an adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BMVHHT47). This would allow you to use your dock.

Your laptop has a USB3 slot in the picture, so you will still get good use out of your dock. The reduced speed might mean that you can only run 1 or 2 displays off the dock instead of the 2 or 3 displays you could run with a newer laptop.

Comment: The adapter you linked is a) data only b) against the specification. If you do want a C female to A male adapter https://www.amazon.com/dp/B074V4QBS4 is active. But it doesn't help OP for sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are a small number of HDMI to USB C adapters, built around the Lontium LT6711GX (HDMI 2.1 to USB C) or LT6711 (HDMI 2.0 to USB C) chipset. One even older device exists which only does HDMI 1.4 to USB C: the Wacom Link Plus.

You can find the actual device lists [here](https://dancharblog.wordpress.com/2020/05/10/bi-directional-usbc-dp-cables/#hdmi-usb-c). Dan usually updates his lists regularly so I am not copying it to avoid becoming outdated. But to have an actual recommendation: https://www.club-3d.com/en/cat/adapter/hdmi/1609/312/ Club 3D has four of them here. To quote one:

> The Club 3D CAC-1332 [...] adapter is Uni-Directional it only works from an HDMI™ Source device to an USB C DisplayPort supported display.

So yes, these devices do exist, have existed since [2018](https://machollywood.com/blogs/news/wacom-link-plus-release) even if they are rare.